# Does Spring contain something similar to BeanUtils populate method?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to populate a pojo with data from a map. I can use Apache Commons but I'm curious if Spring also has an implementation built in.

I know Spring must contain a method that does this mapping; spring integration inbound http gateways will map HTTP payloads to a POJO (request-payload-type).

Is BeanUtils the de facto standard for doing exactly what I want?

Comment: How's the map formatted? Key as field?

Comment: Yes. Assume that BeanUtils populate would work as expected . Mainly curious if Spring has the same functionality built in.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration has this one `MapToObjectTransformer` and it's logic is the same as it is in the case of Spring MVC - `DataBinder`. 
So, I suppose it would be enough just read source code of [MapToObjectTransformer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/transformer/MapToObjectTransformer.java).

Answer (score -1):

`Spring` also contains the `BeanUtils`.

Refer the following link:

[org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html)

Comment: -1: Spring BeanUtils doesn't have a method taking a Map (I assume the ones taking a pair of Objects don't work - correct me if I'm wrong).